# How to extract content from a given url's document using gwt?

Tags: javascript, gwt, web-scraping

I'm new to GWT and am trying to build a web scraping app.
I have a custom URL, say www.amazon.com. 
I want to be able to open this url, scrape information from its source (preferably by storing the html content as a Document in gwt) and print the scraped info on the console.

I've tried creating an iframe in the current page and setting its src to the custom url. But that didn't work out.

Do tell me if you need me to elaborate / clarify any aspect of the question

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrap the URL on the server and write the output through a servlet. Open this Servlet URL in a Dialog box in GWT.

Or if the content (of the scrapped page) can be stored in other formats like a HashMap, then you can RPC the server to get the data object and display it in an HTML panel at the client side.

Thanks,
Sreehari.